# Prove that $H'$ and $\Phi_a$, respectively defined by (8.207) and (8.208), are first-class functions (Nivaldo Lemos, problem 8.9.2)

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

I'm having trouble to solve this problem. In the book Analytics Mechanics, Nivaldo Lemos define two equations:

- Equation (8.207):

$$ H' = H + \sum_{m=1}^M U_m\phi_m $$

- Equation (8.208):

$$ \Phi_a = \sum_{m=1}^M V_m^{(a)}\phi_m $$

I'm not sure of how to prove that $H'$ and $\Phi_a$ are first-class functions. I know I need to use the Poisson brackets and show that all of them equals zero, but I'm not sure of how to do this properly.

Thank you for the help!